# Using Entity Framework in separate web project but can't connect due to Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: entity-framework

I've built my entity model in a separate C# class library project than my web project. In my separate class library project I created some simple classes that are representations of the entity classes for passing to the client through AJAX. In the simple objects I create the context for querying the database. When I call methods in those classes from my web application, I can't seem I keep getting errors. At first it was because I had nothing in my web.config file referencing the connection string from the project with the entity model. I copied the three tags from the app.config file to my web.config file but now I see an error: Keyword not supported: 'metadata' when trying to query the database.

One thing I'm not sure about is where to create the context. Should that be done in the web project then passed to methods in the class library project? When I try this approach I get the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

If I create the context in the class library project, when running the application and trying to query the database I get the keyword not supported: 'metadata' error. So I'm not sure where to go here. What am I doing wrong? I've spent hours searching for an answer but there are so much info out there I couldn't find anything specific to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either you should add reference to `EntityFramework` in your web project or you should abstract away your context class behind an interface. Search for `Repository pattern` implementation for `EntityFramework`.

Comment: I figured out why I was seeing the "You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'." error. I went into the Library Package Manager and clicked "Manage" next to the Entity Framework. That showed that it was included only in the project with the model. Once I added it to the web project, the error went away. But I still get the Keyword not supported metadata. If I remove it and the provider related keywords then I get an error that my connection string doesn't meet specifications. So I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I'm getting a silent error when creating my context. If I hover over the context and drill down I see this error: Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection'." Not sure why this would be happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a class library using EntityFramework, VS will automatically add it as an installed package, but only for the class library project.  You have to go back into the NuGet Package Manager for the solution and add that package to your other project(s)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed fix this by editing the web.config file. I needed to change the providerName from System.Data.SqlClient to System.Data.EntityClient. I'm not sure how it got switched but now it's working. Also note the comment above to get rid of the You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'." error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I experienced a similar problem, with the following errors:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Model.Net\ProductManager.cs 16  17  MyProject.Model.Net
Error   2   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Model.Net\ProductManager.cs 17  17  MyProject.Model.Net
Error   3   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<MyProject.Data.ProductInventoryView>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<MyProject.Data.ProductInventoryView>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Model.Net\ProductManager.cs 18  21  MyProject.Model.Net
Error   4   Metadata file 'C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Model.Net\bin\Debug\MyProject.Model.Net.dll' could not be found  C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Web\CSC MyProject.Web
```

To solve this problem I needed to add the EntityFramework.dll reference the MyProject.Data project by browsing to this directory to select the file: ~\MyProject\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll